# How to align div to bottom in parent element

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the foundation framework to create a website, I am having a little trouble aligning a `div` class container to the bottom of the parents container.

Here is a photo of the problem.

[image: Image 1]

Notice the first image, everything is aligned properly. The second image on the other hand the `<div>` content is way off. I have it set to `bottom:0;` in the css but it's not working.

Here is the CSS:

```
.container-home {
  max-width: 1175px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.first-title-music {
  background: url('http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/large-title.png');
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 425px;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5% 0 0 3%;
  clear: bottom;
}

.artist-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.song-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.big-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 170px;
}

.second-title-music {
  background: url('http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/small-title.png');
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 190px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.artist-title-small {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.song-title-small {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.big-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 170px;
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<div class="row container-home">
  <div class="row column" style="position:relative; padding:15px 0 0 2%;">
    <div class="medium-6 column" style="max-width:425px; margin:0px; padding:0;">
      <img src="http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/mario2.png">
      <div class="medium-4 column first-title-music">
        <h1 class="artist-title">MARIO</h1>
        <h1 class="song-title">I NEED MORE</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="large-12 column big-play">
        <img src="http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/big-play2.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 column" style="max-width:190px;max-height:190px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left;">
      <img src="http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/alicia2.png">
      <div class="medium-4 column second-title-music">
        <h1 class="artist-title-small">ALICIA KEYS</h1>
        <h1 class="song-title-small">IN COMMON</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Image 2]

Does anyone have a solution as to why the bottom aligned `<div>` in the second part of the html code is stretching that far beyond the height of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row container-home">
      <div class="row column newclass">
        <div class="medium-6 column bottomdiv" style="">
          <img src="http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/mario2.png" class="img1">
          <div class="medium-4 column first-title-music">
            <h1 class="artist-title" style="">MARIO</h1>
            <h1 class="song-title">I NEED MORE</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="large-12 column big-play">
            <img src="http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/big-play2.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-6 column newclass2" style="">
          <img src="http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/alicia2.png">
          <div class="medium-4 column second-title-music">
            <h1 class="artist-title-small">ALICIA KEYS</h1>
            <h1 class="song-title-small">IN COMMON</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

/* Put your css in here */

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}

.container-home {
  max-width: 1175px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px 0 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.first-title-music {
  background: url('http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/large-title.png');
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 425px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* padding: 5% 0 0 3%; */
  clear: bottom;
  top: 331px;
}

.artist-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.song-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.big-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 170px;
}

.second-title-music {
  background: url('http://cdn.ratedrnb.com/2016/06/small-title.png');
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 190px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* padding: 5% 0 0 3%; */
  clear: bottom;
  top: 135px;
}

.artist-title-small {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.song-title-small {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.big-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 170px;
}

.newclass {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0 0 2%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottomdiv {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 425px;
}

.artist-title,
.song-title {
  margin-left: 60px !important;
}

.newclass2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 190px;
  max-height: 190px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.artist-title-small,
.song-title-small {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}

.img1 {
  height: 425px;
  width: 425px;
}
```

and the link https://plnkr.co/edit/52Ga8dT6wpTRklGDtvMX?p=preview for ref

Comment: That actually didn't help for the second line :(

Comment: send me a full Html then

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to "dock" a panel to the bottom using absolute position which could kill your app's ability to be mobile responsive, why not structure your html to better support what you're trying to accomplish. You'll end up with simpler css that way too.

For example, you seem to be attempting to accomplish this:

```css
.darkgray { background: #999;}
.parent-panel {width: 600px; margin: auto; }
.left-panel  {float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 10px;}
.right-panel {float: left; width: calc(100% - 220px);}
.right-child {float: left; width: calc(33.33% - 20px); height: 90px; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent-panel">
  <div class="left-panel darkgray"></div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    <div class="right-child darkgray"></div>
    <div class="right-child darkgray"></div>
    <div class="right-child darkgray"></div>
    <div class="right-child darkgray"></div>
    <div class="right-child darkgray"></div>
    <div class="right-child darkgray"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```